# Why do I have 2 network addresses for one interface?

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, ip-address

I logged onto my home server through SSH today and noticed that I now had 2 local addresses for the same Ethernet interface, `enp5s0`:

```
IPv4 address for docker0: 172.17.0.1
IPv4 address for enp5s0:  192.168.0.85
IPv4 address for enp5s0:  192.168.0.49
```

On my router, I assigned the server the static address `192.168.0.49`, and today I've noticed that it now has a second address, `192.168.0.85`, how could this have happened, and is it a concern?

`ifconfig` only seems to show this new address:

```
enp5s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.85  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::aaa1:59ff:fe33:9f43  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether a8:a1:59:33:9f:43  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10511  bytes 9516719 (9.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 5  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7159  bytes 697001 (697.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

No one else has access to the server except me - could a program be doing this?

I haven't noticed anything different regarding the services running on it.

I'm running Ubuntu Server 20.04.3.

Comment: Did you upgrade your system from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS?  If so, do you have an `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file?  If you do, you might want to add a `denyinterfaces enp5s0` towards the bottom of the file to prevent `dhcpcd` from adding another DHCP IP to the interface.

Comment: @Terrance Nah, I installed 20.04 directly back in March on a brand new SSD

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: @pigeonburger Where exactly are you seeing both IP addresses?